# QTableWidgetItem ESC signal pressed

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots, qtablewidget

I have a *QThread* which updates a *QTableWidget* column values. When the user doubleclicks on a row of that column the *QThread* stops updating values to let the user edit last read value.

If the users presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> then `cellChanged(int, int)` signal is emitted and I am able to continue updating values. But in case <kbd>Esc</kbd> I get no change signal and I don't know when to restart updating new values.

If I reimplement *QTableView* eventfilter method to listen to <kbd>Esc</kbd> key I can restart the update of values but only if I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> key 2 times. The first time I get out of the *QTableWidgetItem*. Is it possible to listen to it in first place?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is a notification that cell editing has finished, regardless of how that may have happened.

One way to achieve that is to reimplement one of the virtual methods responsible for the editing of cells, and then use that to emit a custom signal:

```
class TableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    editingFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def closeEditor(self, widget, hint):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.closeEditor(self, widget, hint)
        self.editingFinished.emit()
```